# Devise redirect instead of create - Catarse platform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

https://github.com/catarse/catarse

Why is Devise redirecting instead of adding the user to the database? On the local machine everything is fine:

```
App 18981 stdout: Started POST "/en/sign_up" for ... at 2015-07-28 05:08:34 -0400
App 18981 stdout: Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
App 18981 stdout:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Ti/CgGvzauy/neVnvPtc+aBEc5NGKRD0SVPqYLL6+J8=", "user"=>{"email"=>"test678777@gmail.com", "show_password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "newsletter"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign me up", "locale"=>"en"}
App 18981 stdout: Redirected to ...homepage...
App 18981 stdout: Completed 302 Found in 139ms (ActiveRecord: 14.3ms)
App 18981 stdout: Started GET "/en" for ... at 2015-07-28 05:08:34 -0400
```

---

Create action in the production env. in a console works fine.

```
2.2.2 :056 >    User.create(email: "1231222232212312@mail.ru", password: "password")
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" = '1231222232212312@mail.ru' LIMIT 1
  SQL (4.5ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "encrypted_password", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2015-07-29 03:09:25.623040"], ["email", "1231222232212312@mail.ru"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$h60hw3at5glyZMtFRt6UiuPEhaUOWa8dNzqU.8fK91XTKNavHWZA2"], ["updated_at", "2015-07-29 03:09:25.623040"]]
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "user_notifications" ("created_at", "from_email", "from_name", "locale", "template_name", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2015-07-29 03:09:25.630950"], ["from_email", "test@gmail.com"], ["from_name", "Fundinar"], ["locale", "en"], ["template_name", "new_user_registration"], ["updated_at", "2015-07-29 03:09:25.630950"], ["user_id", 9]]
   (0.6ms)  COMMIT
```

Comment: Do you have any validations in your `User` model? If they fail, it will redirect you instead of saving the object.

Comment: Yes, but I fill the same information both forms and on the local machine it works. And I have no errors, just skipping.

Comment: @VitalyFry Where are you redirected? Where is the redirect happening? What is different between production and development? Can you create a user in the console in production? We need more information to help diagnose this.

Comment: @eirikir Now creating in production(console) forks fine. Redirecting to the home page and it's OK too. Different between environments that's in production skipping activerecord things and does redirect immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to replace all values with `catarse.me` in `settings` table. It helped.